# comma in image name gives 404 not found

Tags: html, apache

Edit -- *the problem is not the comma.  I think it is related to WordPress, maybe either .htaccess or a plugin.  I uploaded the same files to a different server, one not running WordPress, and there is no problem.  Any suggestions appreciated.*

I have images with commas in their filenames and they throw a 404 not found error.  I have had images on my web sites like this for years and never noticed a problem.

Example, both the files in the code below exist on the server and are identical, only the comma has been removed from the file name for the second one:

```
<ol>
<li><img src="https://cloud-assn.org/wp-content/cfa_images/Cloud,GeoHarlan.jpg"><br>Cloud,GeoHarlan.jpg</li>
<li><img src="https://cloud-assn.org/wp-content/cfa_images/CloudGeoHarlan.jpg"><br>CloudGeoHarlan.jpg</li>
</ol>
```

The site is running Apache 2.4.29 on a Windows server (3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.4.79.el7.x86_64)

I have literally thousands of images with commas in them.  I've never noticed a problem before today (when I ran Xenu link checker) and it now appears those images aren't found by the server.  (I can see them via FTP)

Comment: Commas seem to be causing alot of problems in URLs: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=comma+in+urls

Comment: I just copied the files to a different server and there is no problem.  The http://cloud-assn.org site is a WordPress site and I'm wondering if there is something in .htaccess causing this problem?